# Adding texture with transparency in Blender Cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, transparency

I need help desperately.

I don't know why the part that's supposed to be transparent is coming up with these checkers, it doesn't show in the material preview only when I render.

[image: see picture]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: That looks like your image isn't really transparent.  If not, maybe it's "z fighting" because your plane that has the image on it is too close to the background plane.  Can you share a blend file that has the image packed into it so we can check it out? 
([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Answer (score 1):

If your image has actual alpha values, then a shader along these lines will preserve the transparency:

[image: Image texture using transparency]

This is the sort of material that the *Images as Planes* add-on will generate automatically when you insert an image as a plane, for example.  The key is that the *Image Texture* node has an *alpha* output that has to be connected to the *alpha* input of the *Principled* BSDF node.

Do be aware that sometimes when you download what seems to be an image with transparency, rather than getting the version of the file that has the transparency the downloader will sometimes substitute a gif, that has the checkered background, like this example:

[image: Image with "transparency" that has been converted to gif]

This is one possible explanation for your issue; especially if you've used a material like the one I show above.

The other common explanation doesn't usually generate a regular checkered pattern, but it is [z-fighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting). This can happen if you have your image too close to a plane directly behind it.  The solution for z-fighting would be to move your image slightly above the plane that it is fighting with.

Comment: my image has transparency because I removed the background in photoshop and the texture worked in maya. i gave what you said about it being too close to the other plane and you were right, that was the problem. thank you so much, is there a way for them to be close together and not have an issue? or is that something blender does not allow?

Comment: @Haru There's a limit to how close they can be because of the way Blender does z buffer calculations.  I end up just experimenting to get as close as is reasonable myself.